# compose inspection is not available

Tags: android-studio

[android studio screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp743.png)
Layout inspector is not available, due to that I can't see compose tree

I tried to resolve the problem of layout inspector by following some source from stack overflow but couldn't get the result. I'm expecting that this work as normally.

Comment: Same here. Did you solve this?